# MS CRM - Duplicate tracking tokens when sending emails from workflows

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, tracking, token, dynamics-crm-4

I have recently helped some of our users set up several workflows to send emails. Now that these have been in use for a couple of weeks we have noticed that each time the workflow runs, emails to different recipients are sometimes given the same email Tracking Token. This has resulted a number of emails tracking to the wrong Lead when their recipient replies.

For a workflow that sends the same email to 10 - 15 people most of the emails sent will receive a unique tracking code, however between 2 and 5 from the same workflow execution  frequently have the same Tracking Token appended.

Emails sent using the standard send email functionality consistently have unique Tracking Tokens.

No custom code or 3rd party add ons are being used in the email sending process. We are running CRM version 4.0, and are yet to perform roll up 7 (we are in the process of doing that at the moment). |We have also disabled smart matching, and rely on the tracking codes.

Finally the workflow sends the email from an email template.

Thanks

Update:

Workflow Screen shot url: http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/4710/stackoverflowworkflowsc.png (I haven't been a member long enough to post the image)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of an example of one of the workflows where this issue occurs?

Comment: Matt, Thanks for getting back to me - I have added a link to a screen shot of the workflow above.

Comment: So, how do they run the workflow? Would they just highlight a series of 15 or so leads, and then run that workflow on demand against all of them?

Comment: From an advanced find they select the appropriate leads and then run the workflow from there. 

I think it might be a threading problem (as the workflows are executed asynchronously) with the tracking ID being updated only after it has been requested by a number of other emails. 

Am looking at ways of slowing down the workflow so it only sends the email after an arbitrary amount of time - quite a nasty hack, but it will at least confirm that is the problem.